# Is there a way to set autocommit as true for all connections made by an engine?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a postgresql engine that is executing some commands, and I would like all of them to be autocommited.

Using elections options for every statement seems like it would be a lot of unnecessary code:

```
engine.execute(text("SELECT * FROM table").execution_options(autocommit=True))
engine.execute(text("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table").execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

compared to something like:

```
engine = create_engine(my_db, autocommit=True)
engine.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
engine.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table")
```

In the docs it says that the execution_options method is available on Connection, Engine, and Executable classes, so I tried:

`engine = create_engine(my_db, autocommit=True)`

```
engine = create_engine(my_db)
engine.execution_options(autocommit=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

What to do ended up being this:

`engine = create_engine(my_db, isolation_level = "AUTOCOMMIT")`